# Continue executing a thread while another thread is running in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

tl, dr;

I have a GUI thread that creates an object of another class (the seconds class has implemented `Runnable`, but here we don't execute the `run()` method, instead, we call a normal method) and calls a method. In that method, the first thread (current thread) is called again (to show sth on the LCD), then sends some data to the Internet, and waits 3 seconds for the server response. The problem is that the information is printed after 3 seconds. I know about the `stack` and `program counter`, but I wonder if there is another option that I can do my job.

---

I have the main method, which runs 3 threads (for short, I just write the requisite code. Tell me to add more, if needed):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
        
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI.getInstance().setVisible(true); //GUI is singleton, using swing and JFrame
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        MQTTConnection.getInstance().tryToConnect(); //It's the connection class, which has a thread (the thread is handled by a library that keeps the connection alive. I have no threads there) and is a singleton too.

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new SendDataThread()); //A thread which sends some data every 20 seconds.
        t1.start();
    }
```

And in SendDataThread, I have a function that creates some random data and sends them (using the MQTTConnection class).

This is the `SendDataThread`:

```
public class SendDataThread implements Runnable {
    
    public void sendLog() {
        boolean serverOnline = false;
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.append(createData());
        GUI.getInstance().printNeutral(data.toString()); //Prints BLACK on a `JTextPane`
        
        if(MQTTConnection.getInstance().publishLog(MQTTConnection.getInstance().MQTT_PUBLISH_ESP_SEND_LOG, data.toString())) //This line has a 3 second timeout. If the server doesn't respond, it will return false. I've added the 3 seconds timeout too. Please continue reading.
            serverOnline = true;
        
        if(serverOnline)
            GUI.getInstance().printOK("Server Submitted"); //Prints in GREEN
        else
            GUI.getInstance().printProblem("Check your connection!"); //Prints in RED
        
        GUI.getInstance().printNeutral("-------------------------------------------------");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            sendLog();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000); //sleeps 20 about seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
//.....
}
```

And this is the 3 seconds timeout method, in `MQTTConnection`:

```
    boolean publishLog(String topic, String data){
        mqtt_responds = false;
        publish(topic, data);
        System.out.println("MQTT is connected");
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime < callback_timeout) {
            if(mqtt_responds){
                mqtt_responds = false;
                System.out.println("Server submitted");
                return true;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Timeout");
        return false;
    }
```

Till now, everything work right. The problem starts where I have a button in the GUI class, which the user can manually send random logs:

```
        JButton sendLogBtn = new JButton("Send Log");
        sendLogBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SendDataThread sdt = new SendDataThread();
                sdt.sendLog();
            }
        });
        sendLogBtn.setBounds(10, 331, 89, 23);
        panel.add(sendLogBtn);
```

This button creates an object of `SendDataThread` and calls the `sendLog()` method. The issue happens here: after `sendLog()` is called, `sendLog()`, calls this GUI thread again:

```
-->     GUI.getInstance().printNeutral(data.toString()); //Prints BLACK on a `JTextPane`
```

But the log is printed after 3 seconds (After the `sendLog()` method has finished working, the timeout!)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are blocking the EDT with the `sendLog` which is called by the button's `actionPerformed`. This is why the BLACK is printed after 3 seconds.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but I would guess you should be using a `SwingWorker`. With a `SwingWorker` you can run a background Thread and when you receive data in the Thread you can "publish" the results to the GUI. Check out the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) especially the section on "Tasks That Contain Interim Results".

Comment: @gthanop: yes, you are right, the `Thread.sleep` is being called on the EDT. Not good.

Comment: You can make as many threads as you want, but Swing only runs in one particular thread (created and managed by the Java runtime).  If you block that thread in your ActionListener, Swing cannot redraw anything and cannot process user input.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Comment: @gthanop Aha, thanks. Is this just because of Swing? I mean what if I have my own 2 threads? Does a thread blocks itself and waits for the other thread?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As you said, "`Thread.sleep`" is not a good idea. What should I do instead?

Comment: Instead of `Thread.sleep` in a loop, you can use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and post your `Runnable`s (ie `SendDataThread`s) there. But don't forget to invoke Swing related code on the EDT.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi *What should I do instead?* - so you haven't read the tutorial yet? Two people have given you the link to the tutorial! You can use Thread.sleep(...) if you follow the examples in the  tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button's `actionPerformed` you are calling `sendLog`. `sendLog` does exactly what you said, ie reports some logs and waits about 3 seconds (assuming `callback_timeout` is about equal to `3000`).

To fix this, you need to make sure that the 3sec blocking is not on the EDT and also to make sure that the logs are instead posted on the EDT.

As a quick workaround you can do:

```
sendLogBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Thread(() -> new SendDataThread().sendLog()).start();
    }
});
```

and then, as always, post your logs in the EDT like for example:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> GUI.getInstance().printNeutral(...));
```

AND

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> GUI.getInstance().printProblem(...));
```

AND

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> GUI.getInstance().printOk(...));
```

As for [the question in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702125/continue-executing-a-thread-while-another-thread-is-running-in-java#comment121414335_68702125), I don't really understand what you are asking, but I should say that (as far as I know) the EDT is a `Thread` where all the Swing code is (and should be) posted on for execution. This way the Swing code does not have to be `synchronized`, because all GUI related stuff is executed sequentially (on the EDT). AWT for example was not intended to be single threaded as far as I know. Swing is however single threaded.

Comment: This is creating a new thread, and when I start it, what happens? I have `while(true)` in my `run()` method. I don't want that. I just want the `sendLog()`.

Comment: I am sorry. I mistakenly started a new `SendDataThread` instead of calling `sendLog`. Now I've fixed it. In my opinion you can post some more code (eg a [mre])... For example what does `createData` do?

Comment: Thanks. createData() does nothing important. It just creates some random data and returns a string like: `{"temp": 19.8, "humidity": 80}`

Comment: No, please don't suggest use of static. No reason to throw out the OOP baby with the bathwater. Better to use dependency injection or other low-coupling technique to connect classes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh ok.

Comment: @gthanop What if I have a variable like time, which is initialized in `run()` method, and I want to set it in another method? I can't call `new Thread(() -> new SendDataThread().setTime(epoch)).start();`, it returns `NullPointerException`. What should I do?

Comment: Please post a [mre] so that I can identify the cause, because as it is wright now, I cannot identify a NPE.

Comment: @gthanop Problem with time is solved. Thank you a lot.